# Python: What's the proper way to convert between python bool and numpy bool_?

Tags: numpy, boolean

I kept getting errors with a numpy ndarray with booleans not being accepted as a mask by a pandas structure when it occured to me that I may have the 'wrong' booleans. **Edit**: it was not a raw numpy array but a pandas.Index.

While I was able to find a solution, the only one that worked was quite ugly:

```
mymask = mymask.astype(np.bool_) #ver.1 does not work, elements remain <class 'bool'>
mymask = mymask==True #ver.2, does work, elements become <class 'numpy.bool_'>
mypdstructure[mymask]
```

What's the proper way to typecast the values?

Comment: What kind of errors? numpy and pandas play very well together. Are you sure this is not just an issue of labels?

Comment: "IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type". I'm fairly sure that things are otherwise correct because I get the results I expect using ver.2

Comment: Do you have NaNs in `mymask`? Or something else that may cause upcasting the dtype of the array?

Comment: @JohnSmith  What version of numpy?  I can not reproduce your result on numpy 1.13.1 / Python 3.6.0.  Both ways give `np.bool_` in the array.

Comment: @ayhan no. I checked the output and it's only True or False

Comment: @wim It's numpy version 1.13.0 and Python 3.6.3. More specifically running on Kaggle's jupyter notebook variant.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the original problem description. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem. My original post was not fully correct: my mask was a pandas.Index.

It seems that the pands.Index.astype is behaving unexpectedly (for me), as I get different behavior for the following:

```
mask = pindex.map(myfun).astype(np.bool_) # doesn't cast
mask = pindex.map(myfun).astype(np.bool_,copy=False) # doesn't cast
mask = pindex.map(myfun).values.astype(np.bool_) # does cast
```

Maybe it is actually a pandas bug? This result is surprising to me because I was under the impression that pandas is usually just calling the functions of the numpy arrays that it is based on. This is clearly not the case here.

Comment: Yeah, index.astype silently ignores the bool option as I can see. There are different index versions like Int64Index and Float64Index but there is no BoolIndex; that's probably the reason here but I would expect it to raise an error. Anyway, here are the steps to reproduce if anyone is interested in opening an issue: `a = pd.Index([True, False]); a = a.astype('bool')`

Comment: By the way, if you are working on someone else's code the issue might stem from the fact that the behaviour of `index.map` changed recently. It used to return a numpy array.